# Stop Windows from constantly creating the IE Favorites folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, favorites

Windows 10 21H1 and all other versions of Windows I've ever used insist on creating the Favorites folder, e.g. `C:\Users\John\Favorites`.

For the non-initiated the Favorites folder is created by the part of Windows that handles HTML and Internet Explorer. Disabling Internet Explorer (there was never an option to actually remove it) does not prevent Windows from constantly recreating the folder.

- No - this folder appears in My Documents (or the latest bad-marketing rebrand: "User Files").
- No - I do not want to change the folder's location.
- No - I do not want to create a batch program that deletes it and is required to run every X iterations.

What registry setting forces Windows to stop recreating the Favorites folder?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be one. Why does it bother you?

Comment: C:\Users\John\Favorites.  ...   Is the location of my Chromium Edge favorites - all my curent ones. No mention of IE, not even on my Windows 7 VM where I replaced IE wit Edge.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: NO . My browser is not broken at all. It works perfectly. I think your machine may have an issue. Windows 11 (both my machines) changed the location but Windows 10 is as above.

Comment: Question is about Windows 10 not Windows 11. While similar what exists on Windows 11 isn’t applicable to Windows 10; Internet Explorer doesn’t exist on Windows 11. Internet Explorer is due to be permanently removed from all supported versions of Windows within the next year.

Comment: There sure are a lot of "I don't want to help on a help site" comments here.